# SQL Expiration Date Trigger

Tags: sql, date, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger for a table containing certain keys that are assigned to certain ID's.

Here's what I was trying to do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER expirationDateCheck
BEFORE UPDATE ON sp
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF DATE_ADD(OLD.date,INTERVAL 10 DAY) > CURDATE() THEN
SET OLD.sid=0,OLD.cid=0
END IF
END
```

Basically every time something is about to be put into the sp table I want to first go through the table, find any rows where the current date is later than ten days past the date assigned to the row, and set their sid's and cid's to 0.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you feel it necessary to do this in a trigger? These types of maintenance activities are usually performed by a stored procedure that is run on a schedule.

Comment: also - this is a mutation... so will be difficult to work around (but not impossible depending on the RDBMS)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Things like triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - and *SQL* is just the structured query language - but not a database product...

Answer (score 0):

In a trigger operation, FOR EACH ROW means 'each row affected by the triggering operation', not 'each row that exists in the table'.  Therefore, if you fixed this syntactically, it would only operate on rows as they are updated.

Syntactically, you are probably looking for an UPDATE statement within the action:

```
 UPDATE sp SET sid = 0, cid = 0 WHERE DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 10 DAY) > CURDATE()
```

give or take the OLD or NEW qualifiers.  In some versions of SQL (such as Standard SQL), you need a REFERENCING clause:

```
ON sp REFERENCING OLD AS OLD, NEW AS NEW
```

Well, that's the notation I use in Informix, which allows it; you might need to specify some alias other than OLD and NEW, or your DBMS may implicitly use the referencing notation with OLD and NEW.  Since you don't mention the DBMS, it is hard to be definitive about that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this in a trigger.  You might think you want to, but that's not what triggers are for.  There are lots of reasons not to abuse them, not least of which is that they'll bite you if you do.

You probably don't even want to update the rows!  Instead of saying, *let me update the rows over 10 days old*, create a view that returns those columns as zero (or eliminates such rows, etc.) for rows older than 10 days.  This saves you periodic maintenance and needless I/O, preserves the actual, true data, and moots the question of when the table was last updated for the 10-day check.